# How can I properly combine map() and rand() in Julia?

Tags: arrays, types, mapping, julia

I am using Zygote in Julia, and I have some code that is supposed to loop through two objects of the same dimensions and, for every item of length less than `<= 1`, randomly choose between that part of/for either the first or the second object. The code may better explain what I am attempting to do:

```
function rangeThrough(parent1, parent2)
    child = map(x -> if length(x[1]) > 1 rangeThrough(x[1], x[2]) else rand([x[1] x[2]]) end, zip(parent1, parent2))
    return child
end

aa = [Float32[0. 0. 0. 0.], Float32[0. 0. 0.], Float32[0.]]

bb = [Float32[1. 1. 1. 1.], Float32[1. 1. 1.], Float32[1.]]

Zygote.Params(rangeThrough(aa, bb))
```

The output that I get for the last line of code is something like the following:

```
Params([Float32[1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0], Float32[0.0 0.0 1.0], 0.0])
```

However, what I am trying to achieve is:

```
Params([Float32[1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0], Float32[0.0 0.0 1.0], Float32[0.0]])
```

I have tried a few things but wasn't able to get it working yet. I am not sure why it is that the last number is not contained in a `Float32[]` array. What could I do differently to correct this?

Edit:
By simplifying the code to only accept one list as input, like so:

```
function tempRangeThrough(parent1)
    child = map(x -> if length(x) > 1 tempRangeThrough(x) else rand([x]) end, parent1)
    return child
end
Zygote.Params(tempRangeThrough(aa))
```

I get the intended output:

```
Params([Float32[0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0], Float32[0.0 0.0 0.0], Float32[0.0]])
```

So, I believe this is related to the properties of `zip()`, but I'm not positive how to fix this.

Comment: Is the object arbitrarily nested? Or is it just an array of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want something like this:

```
julia> rangeThrough(p1, p2) = [length(a) > 1 ? a : rand((a,b)) for (a, b) in zip(p1, p2)]
rangeThrough (generic function with 1 method)

julia> rangeThrough(aa, bb)
3-element Array{Array{Float32,N} where N,1}:
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [1.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really get what behaviour you seek exactly, but wanted to mention that `map` can take n-ary functions, too -- so you don't need `zip` here.  And combining with a `do`-block, the function could look as follows:

```
julia> range_through(parent1, parent2) = map(parent1, parent2) do x, y
           if length(x) > 1
               return x
           else
               return rand((x, y))
           end
       end
range_through (generic function with 1 method)

julia> range_through(aa, bb)
3-element Array{Array{Float32,N} where N,1}:
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0]    
 [1.0]
```